# What's the difference between ">/dev/null 2>&1" and "2>/dev/null >&2"

Tags: linux, shell

I have a question for redirection.
I always use `anycommands > /dev/null 2>&1` when I need not any output. But I have never used `anycommands 2> /dev/null >&2`

**Question:** Which one is the best way to expect no outputs? What's the difference between `anycommands > /dev/null 2>&1` and `anycommands 2> /dev/null >&2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

case#1:`(echo stdout;echo stderr>&2) >/dev/null 2>&1`

- stdout(1) is replaced by an fd to `/dev/null`
- stderr(2) descriptor is copied from `&1` which now is an fd to `/dev/null`
- result: no output at all

case#2:`(echo stdout;echo stderr>&2) 2>&1 >/dev/null`

- stderr(2) descriptor is copied from `&1` which is the default stdout
- stdout(1) is replaced by an fd to `/dev/null`
- result: `stderr` is empty, `stdout` not shown, `stderr` on `stdout`

case#3: `(echo stdout; echo stderr >&2) 2> /dev/null >&2`

same as case#1, `stderr` and `stdout` have switched roles

Comment: This explains `2>&1 > /dev/null`, but the question asks about `> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Thanks your answer but I'd like to know `(echo stdout; echo stderr >&2) 2> /dev/null >&2` about case#2

Comment: AkihikoTakahashi: same as case#1

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, the two are equivalent.  `cmd > /dev/null 2>&1` connects stdout of the command to `/dev/null`, and then connects stderr to the same file.  `cmd 2>/dev/null >&2`  connects stderr to `/dev/null`, and then connects stdout to it.  The only difference is in the order in which the two streams are associated with `/dev/null`, which has no bearing on the status of the command when it is run.  In both cases, both streams are redirected to the bit bucket.

Comment: They are not equivalent; see Zoltan's answer.

Comment: @Aaron  I do see Zoltan's answer.  He is talking about `2>&1 > /dev/null` which behaves differently than `>/dev/null 2>&1`, and is not what the question is about.

Comment: You're right. I can't undo my downvote unless you edit your question :-(

Answer (score -1):

If you're using only BASH, use `&>` to redirect both stdout and stderr. That's the most compact, safe and simple solution.

Regarding your question, the first one is equivalent to `&>` (it redirects both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.

The second connects stderr to `/dev/null` and redirects stdout to the new stderr, so it's equivalent to as far as the output is concerned. Just the order of file descriptor operations is reversed.

Comment: `&>` is not safe.  It is quite common for shell scripts to be invoked by an unexpected interpreter (eg, the shebang is `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` is something other than bash), and `&>` is not portable.  For example, `dash` will run the command in the background, which is arguably correct behavior according to the standard.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: "If you're using BASH, ..."

Comment: Unfortunately, when the script is invoked by an unexpected interpreter, then you are not using bash.